# Must I setup SSL certificate if my server is listening on only port 443 with Nginx?

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, port-443

I am using Amazon Load Balancer to receive requests on Port 443. Then I am sending off these request to my EC2 server on port 80. If I try to send the request on port 443 to EC2 nginx `error.log` file says,

> no "...ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking...

Therefore, Must I setup SSL certificate if my server is listening on only port 443 with Nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your EC2 instance to listen on port 443 using SSL / TLS you need a certificate.

You can terminate SSL on the load balancer and communicate with the EC2 instance using http.

If you want to use http between the ELB and EC2 instances you should look at compliance. PCI wouldn't allow it, but in practice the AWS internal network is generally considered "secure enough" and using http rather than https between an ELB and EC2 server is sufficiently secure for most workloads.

Comment: Thank you! I understand. Your reply is very helpful.